# Pandas: to_excel() float_format

Tags: excel, pandas, formatting

I'm trying to get the `float_format` parameter working with pandas' `to_excel()` function, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['1/15/2016','2/1/2016','2/15/2016','3/15/2016'],
        'numA':[1000,2000,3000,4000.3],
        'numB':[10000,20000.2,30000,40000]
    })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/.../pandas_excel_test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

print df.dtypes

df.to_excel(writer, 
        index = False,
        float_format = '%.2f',
    )
```

But the Excel file looks like this:

[image]

I confirmed dtypes as:

```
date     object
numA    float64
numB    float64
dtype: object
```

Does anyone know how to properly format floats in `to_excel()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe Excel formatting changes how floats are displayed. I tried `to_csv` method and `float_format` worked. For excel, telling excel how to display the column helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['1/15/2016','2/1/2016','2/15/2016','3/15/2016'],
        'numA':[1000,2000,3000,4000.3],
        'numB':[10000,20000.2,30000,40000]
    })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/.../pandas_excel_test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format1)  # Adds formatting to column C
writer.save()
```

Result:

[image: Final excel result]

More info: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Comment: You're right.  I've been searching and searching and it seems like that's the only real answer.  Which is fine, just needed to change my approach.  Thank you!