# Pandas behavior of handling precision of 00

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is bit silly question but I got stuck where I'm analyzing some data and while doing this pandas behavior is quite bad.

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(abc.csv)

Interaction Rate  Active Time Spent  
0          0.039327              15.01  
1          0.015121               8.97  
2          0.035274              14.00 

write_df = df.to_excel(workbook,sheet_name = 'name')
```

so when I'm writing this data to excel using **to_excel** method it's just removing **.00** from last value of **"Active Time Spent"** column. the data type of that column is **float64**.

Please suggest?

It's not duplicate as the data frame should print the way it's printing on the console until I'm doing some changes on the particular column. its has 14.00 at last of Active time spent and I'm doing nothing as in experimental.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: to\_excel() float\_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423036/pandas-to-excel-float-format)

Comment: @AlexK. It's not duplicate as the data frame should print the way it's printing on the console until I'm doing some changes on the particular column. its has 14.00 at last of Active time spent and I'm doing nothing as in experimental.

Comment: Please add your code!

Comment: @marcuse its just reading from CSV to writing excel.

Comment: @marcuse see edits

Answer (score 1):

> when I'm writing this data to excel using to_excel method it's just removing .00 from last value of "Active Time Spent" column.

That is how Excel works.

If you enter 14.00 in a cell it will display it as 14 (without a decimal place). If you want to display it as 14.00 you need to add a number format in Excel.

Here is an [example of how to do that with Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output).

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the type of your column to string while saving?

I see that saving it as `float` or `str` still changes to a general format in Excel. So, you might as well change it to string to maintain the `.00` decimals.

```
df['Active_Time_Spent'] = df['Active_Time_Spent'].astype(str)
```

Try this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('trial.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
workbook  = writer.book
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, format1)
writer.save()
```

Where A:A can be replaced by the column you want. In your case, perhaps it will be B, the second column that is.

Comment: i think changing the type to str working, but numbers are storing as text on excel file which is not good. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: For me, even if I save it as float, it stores as text in Excel, that is the point I have made.

Comment: when I'm doing this:
df['Active_Time_Spent'] = df['Active_Time_Spent'].astype(float) its stored as number in excel however when doing this

df['Active_Time_Spent'] = df['Active_Time_Spent'].astype(str)
stored as text, which is showing error mark on excel with warning number stored as text.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.