# To add number format to xlxs file using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below in abc.xlxs

```
date,qty,price,profitprice,sellprice
20200501,11,900,,20
```

And using python I want output as:

```
data,qty,price,profitprice,sellprice
20200501,11.00,900.00,,20.00
```

Can any one help on this?

how can I read each column with its value and add number format and save to xlxs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44423449/2827333) by [Akshit Khurana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775446/akshit-khurana):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("initial.xlsx")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("formatted.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('C:E', None, format1)  # Adds formatting to columns C-E
writer.save()
```

I believe the two other answers posted here do not work for the same reason why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423036/pandas-to-excel-float-format) was asked.

Comment: You are welcome! make sure to accept it as the answer then

Comment: When I tried to save this modified xlxs file into csv then the number format gets vanished. Any help on this?

Comment: `df = df.astype({'price': float, 'profitprice': float, 'sellprice': float})` or the solutions from the other 2 answers work for csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dtype parameter at `read_excel`:

```
pd.read_excel('abc.xlxs', dtype={'profitprice': float, 'sellprice': float})
```