# Conversion of numbers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam working with a project that is converting invoice PDFs to excels and comparing values between two different columns, but iam having trouble with something when comparing values, I put the differences into a list, but when i do that python converts numbers like 0.00, 857.60, 36.50 to 0.0 ,857.6 ,36.5 and because of that i cant use .iloc from pandas to locate the values of the columns, because of it removing that last digit it doesn't match the column value, like the column have the value 0.00, but the list has the value 0.0

this is the code to compare two values and append differences to a list

```
for item in values_bank:
  if item not in values_system:
     list_difference.append(item)
```

And this is the .loc to create an dataframe using the matches to the "list_difference"

```
diferencce = df_bank.loc[df_bank['value'].isin(list_difference)]
```

df_bank:

```
           Date             Name                   Value
0    25/02/2022             Lorem  C               0.00
1    02/03/2022            Ipsum   C               100.00
2    02/03/2022          Lorem Ipsum   *           16.90
3    02/03/2022            Lorem  C                2454.00
4    02/03/2022            Ipsum                   3732.00
```

printing only the column values:

```
0          0.00
1        100.00
2         16.90
3       2454.00
4       3732.00
```

list_difference:

```
['0.0', '16.9', '2454.0', '3732.0']
```

Edited to add list_difference and df_bank

Comment: `0.00` is equivalent or rather is EXACTLY EQUAL TO `0.000000` or even `0`. You cannot maintain the last zero after the decimal unless you have characters instead of numbers

Comment: But on both DF it mantained the 0.00 values, it only changes when comparing and then appending the values, is there a command that i can use to append the values as a string instead of float?

Comment: Looks like these numbers are stored as strings in the dataframe?

Comment: Apparently, beacuse in the dataframe it keeps the extra numbers, but for some reason it converts to float when I compare columns

Comment: @JoãoPedro, can you please also edit and include the contents of list_difference, and df_bank['value'], specifically the data types? Because it seems that you are comparing floats with strings, hence the issue.

Comment: Done, it seems like it's not what i tought, the list difference is a list of strings, but for some reason it still removes the last 0

Comment: @JoãoPedro, I've posted my solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data type of `item` while appending to the list:

```
for item in values_bank:
  if item not in values_system:
     list_difference.append(float(item))
```

In this way, `list_difference` will contain floats and the rest of your code should produce the expected outcome. An important caveat to note here is that this type casting operation can result in a value error if the `item` variable contains something that can't be converted to float.

Comment: Yeah, this solved part of the problem, but i ended up runing into another lol, for some reason when using .loc it doesn't find all the values on the bank DF to add to the difference DF, for example, the value 16.9 doesn't go to the difference DF even tough it is on the df_bank

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer so I'm assuming it's working as it should now?

Comment: yeah, the part of the problem that i asked is solved, iam only having trouble with pandas now, but i'll try figuring something out, its just that pandas is removing the decimal house when I use the .to_excel, thanks

Comment: Figured it out, just used xlsxwriter to format it, [Pandas to excel float format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423036/pandas-to-excel-float-format) , if anyone has the same trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.df_bank():
    value = row['Value']
    df.at[index,'Value'] = value
```

"Python treatment" to the DataFrame.
Then you may just use the DataFrame with Python variables.