# Trying to format number columns with pandas without changing type

Tags: python, pandas, format

I am working on automating an Excel process and I want my output to be thousand separated by commas with two decimal places for readability.

I was able to get this to work with this code:

```
merge2_df['LossP'] = merge2_df['LossP'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
merge2_df['ALAEP'] = merge2_df['ALAEP'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
merge2_df['ULAEP'] = merge2_df['ULAEP'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
merge2_df['AAO-ULP'] = merge2_df['AAO-ULP'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

However, this changes the type to a string which I am not looking for. I noticed other people have had this problem and have even had their questions answered on stackoverflow, so I tried to copy what the answers said in this code:

```
merge2_df = merge2_df.style.format({
    'LossP': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'ALAEP':  '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'ULAEP': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'AAO-ULP': '{:,.2f}'.format})
```

For some reason, this does absolutely nothing. No errors and no changes to the format. I tried getting rid of the merge2_df = which does not do anything either. It is not after the to_excel function so the placement of the code should not be an issue. Can anyone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear: Are you trying to update the format of the pandas dataframe, or just have the output in excel be comma-formatted? If the latter, you can use the `float_format` parameter in `to_excel()`. If the former, it's a string after formatting because you're applying string formatting to it. If you want it to behave like a number (for arithmetic purposes, etc) then leave it unformatted. If you want it to look good for human readability, then leave it for the last step and let it be a string

Comment: You can use something like `merge2_df.style.format('{:,}')` but then you're left with a styler object rather than a dataframe, and that doesn't help you either

Comment: I only need the output in Excel to be comma formatted, but I would prefer it to be a float as highlighting the column and looking at the sum is often used as a check to make sure the numbers are right, but that does not work when it is a string. However, it is a bit annoying to compare individual cells with other outputs as they are all comma separated with two decimal places. I can just change it in Excel easily, but I was hoping to include that in the program. I tried using float_format, but I get this error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: I think this is due to having columns that are strings in the df.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423036/pandas-to-excel-float-format) deals specifically with using the `xlswriter` object used in `to_excel` to manipulate the column formats after the workbook is created but before it's saved, might be helpful to you. See also: [xlsxwriter docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html)